# java.lang.IllegalStateException after click on listview

Tags: android, listview, exception

I have problem with listview. every time I run the code, and If I press on listview - program crashes with code:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView
did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class 
android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.SimpleAdapter)]
```

here the code fragment:

```
public void getProfileInformation() {
    frienders();
    System.out.println("STORE" + store);
    String fqlQuery = "SELECT status_id, uid , message FROM status WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
    params.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {

            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            if (graphObject != null) {
                if (graphObject.getProperty("data") != null) {
                    try {
                        String arry = graphObject.getProperty("data").toString();
                        JSONArray jsonNArray = new JSONArray(arry);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonNArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonNArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String uid = jsonObject.getString("uid");
                            String status_id = jsonObject.getString("status_id");
                            String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                            Log.i("Entry", "uid: " + uid + ", \nstatus: " + status_id + ", \nmessage: " + message);
                            final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            name = store.get(uid);
                            map.put("name", name);
                            map.put("status_id", status_id);
                            map.put("message", message);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    contactList.add(map);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    System.out.println("aaaa" + contactList);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "name", "status_id", "message" }, new int[] { R.id.name,
            R.id.email, R.id.mobile });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.requestLayout();
    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Can you suggest me something? Thanks!

Comment: can you format your code and post only the relevant code. you exceptions says you are accessing/modifying ui from doInbackground

Comment: That error message is actually pretty verbose. It explains in great detail what went wrong and tells you how to fix it.  Besides that your problem description does not match your code snippet there. You say it crashes when you "press" the ListView (on item click?). I cannot see any touch or click event handler there. Just to recap: you modify the underlying adapter data without notifying ListView about the changes. Also your call to notifyDataSetChanged before the data is loaded doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView
did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified
from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.
```

You are doing an UI operation (`notifyDataSetChanged ()`)in `non-UI thread`, hence you are getting that exception.Perform the UI operation in main thread(`UI thread`).

Try this:

```
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
         {
            @Override
                public void run() {                                                
                   contactList.add(map);
                   your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
          }});
```